# What would happen if one smeared a generous amount of grease on the gears of the geared turbofan jet engine

Tags: geared-turbofan, gearbox, lubrication

What would happen if one smeared a generous amount of grease on all the gears or parts of the gearbox of the  geared turbofan engine such that no tooth is left without grease to the extent that it is 2cm thick layer of grease and then added the required amount of gearbox oil to the gearbox.  Considering the gearbox run very hot because of the friction and speeds,  would that affect its wear and tear or lengthen the next oil change?

Comment: Are you asking how to "improve" servicing, or how to sabotage an engine?

Comment: Grease is a lubricantI want to know why a thicker lubricant may or may not be desirable for the engine @ZeissIkon

Comment: What grease? Vaseline? Duck fat? Who's doing the smearing, a qualified aviation mechanic or a curious visitor?

Comment: Petroleum grease, the type used on axles and bearings, it would be used by a qualified chemical engineer  in an experiment.  I'm sure in coming up with the exact optimal lubricant thickness, engineers do rigorous and numerous test, e.g engine oil thickness for a piston engine will differ from that of gearbox and axles @DanieleProcida

Comment: Honestly, if you're seriously considering conducting private experiments with the lubrication of aircraft engines, you may as well actually use duck fat. Anything you do that the manufacturer has not advised in its manuals is going to end badly. At least that way you'd earn some notoriety as "that guy who filled the turbofan with duck fat", because I think that notoriety would be the only thing to be gained from this exercise.

Comment: "it would be used by a qualified chemical engineer in an experiment." So, basically, you're asking us what the result of this experiment would be? Isn't it usually the point of experiments that you them, rather than just asking "what-if"s?

Comment: For safety consideration I believe we should not consider such questions, I suggest to remove it.

Comment: I got the answer I wanted, thank you for the comments however though some unpleasant, but the thank you non the less.  I learnt a thing or two about lubrication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grease is oil mixed with a thickener, usually a soap-type compound (an oil with a hydroxide termination that makes it solidify and also makes it hydrophilic).

Adding grease to the recommended oil would change the viscosity, temperature/viscosity curve, reactivity, oxidation resistance, and so forth.  If anyone noticed the change on a routine (pre-rebuild) maintenance check, they'd be rrequired to downcheck the engine for a rebuild due to the incorrect lubricant.

It's also very likely that the added volume (2 cm layer is a bunch) would result in an overfill, assuming the recommended amount of the recommended oil was added afterward; this would lead to overheating, leaks, or even blow seals due to pressure build-up in the gear case.

The end result is that adding grease -- any kind of grease -- to the recommended lubricant will be very likely to shorten the service life of the parts it contacts, by altering the properties of the overall lubrication.  The manufacturer spent a lot of time and money designing the lubrication specification, and any change is virtually certain to be a downgrade.

If an A&P did this during a rebuild, and was caught (for instance, due to an in-flight engine failure) they'd be likely to lose their license, potentially even go to jail (for the Federal version of "reckless endangerment" and "malicious property damage" if nothing worse).

Comment: Interesting tidbit.... In aviation the mixing of lithium soap base (like Aeroshell33) and clay based (like Aeroshell 7) has caused much grief, as they don't like to live together.  Things were made worse by having both types under the same mil spec (MIL-G-82232) and maintenance manuals often just called for grease by the mil spec number.  Most maintenance manuals have had to add extensive admonitions against intermix of clay and lithium.

Comment: The general rule has long been to remove all trace of old grease before regreasing during rebuild (for power tools, never mind aircraft engines).  Of course, there's always a Gomer with a grease gun...

Comment: Thank you for the answer I learnt a lot about lubrication and lubicants

Comment: On aviation components like screwjack ballnuts or non-sealed grease-charged gearboxes, it's possible to recharge the grease on-wing.  You can't get a 100% purge.

Comment: @securitydude5 I am familiar with a particular screw jack actuator that at one time had a gearbox filled with a grease-oil slurry, basically grease diluted with oil to the consistency of a milk-shake.  All that happened was the oil separated from the rest of the grease even faster than normal and leaked out through the dynamic seals, and after 10000 hours the gearbox was caked with dried out grease with teeth worn down to nubs.  A later iteration of the actuator just went with synthetic oil and better seals.